# Sql order by ascending, some values are not in acending order

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have an SQL statement that orders the table in ascending order via the id, but when I do this, the table shows it like:

```
c-10
c-12
c-12
c-24
c-5
c-6
c-80
c-800
c-8000
```

As this shows that the top few and bottom few are in order but not the other part. Why is this? As I have tried ordering by my other fields in the table and they appear fine, it's just this column. Do you think this could be an input error or something else?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you think this is not in order, remember it is based on the collation sequence, and C-24 is lower than C-5.    If you want a numeric sort, you need to remove the C- from the expression

Comment: I see now that its sorted lexicographical, i wasnt aware of this until now, as a thought it would appear C-5, c-6 then c-10 etc

Comment: if a was to remove the - from the ids, would that sort it smallest number first as the value is a number after c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is OK, sql sorts the strings in lexical order.

As 2 (in c-24) comes before 5 (in c-5) it is sorted like that.

If you want to sort stings like this in the numeric order prepend them with zeros.

c-0010 c-0012 c-0012 c-0024 c-0005 c-0006 c-0080 c-0800 c-8000 will be sorted as you want it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select column
from your_table
order by to_number(regexp_substr(column, '\d+'))
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/967a4/3)